# HBase 0.92 Standalone on Windows with Cygwin

Tags: java, cygwin, hbase

Does anybody know a tutorial how HBase can be run on Windows under Cygwin?

I managed to setup everything such as the keys for auto login with SSH but Im stuck with following error message:

```
localhost: +======================================================================+
localhost: |      Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and Java could not be found         |
localhost: +----------------------------------------------------------------------+
localhost: | Please download the latest Sun JDK from the Sun Java web site        |
localhost: |       > http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/ <                      |
localhost: |                                                                      |
localhost: | HBase requires Java 1.6 or later.                                    |
localhost: | NOTE: This script will find Sun Java whether you install using the   |
localhost: |       binary or the RPM based installer.                             |
localhost: +======================================================================+
```

...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

I already set .bash_profile to point to:

```
export JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jre1.6.1'
```

which is symbolic link on the real jre

```
/usr/lib/jre1.6.1 -> /cygdrive/c/Java/jre7/
```

Comment: Do you get any output for "java -version" ?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and I found following:
Cygwin use ":" as a path separator. 
But script that creates CLASS_PATH works incorrectly. Final CLASS_PATH looks like 
"...:zookeeper.jar:" with ":" at the end. Before run java script converting  CLASS_PATH to Windows style. But with ":" at the end !!

So my solution is: just **create an empty file "zzz.jar" under hbase/lib**. 
zzz.jar will be very last in CLASS_PATH and zookeeper.jar will be added to CLASS_PATH correctly.

*I know it is better to fix script, but I who cares :) 
I need HBase for 2 days only, so it works and I am happy :)*

Comment: Thanks ever so much! HBase 0.94.7 worked fine for me in cygwin, I just had to set HBASE_CLASSPATH to the lib folder as mentioned in Hisham's answer. However when I came back to it later recently at 0.94.16 that fix no longer seems to work, but your zzz.jar did the trick beautifully.

Answer (score 4):

For `JAVA_HOME` error, you can fix it by setting `JAVA_HOME` in the `hbase\conf\hbase-env.sh`.

For the class not found exception, try adding the `hbase\lib` to the `HBASE_CLASSPATH` under the same file.

Personally, I use the following two lines in my `hbase-env.sh` on a Windows 7 Environment + Cygwin:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/

export HBASE_CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/programs/hbase-0.92.1/lib/
```

Comment: Having this same problem (win7 with cygwin), and this fixed it. No CP errors so far though.

Answer (score 1):

Use a VM to run hadoop in a Linux environment. With Java you may be facing issues typical under windows, adding Cygwin to the mix adds a whole other set, for example:

- [spaces in the include path](http://ist.berkeley.edu/as-ag/technology/howto/install-java-sdk-win.html)
- multiple installations of java from different applications (e.g. browser plugins) can mess up the consistency of the the CLASSPATH, JAVA_HOME and PATH variables
- [shell script path/syntax issues](http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2008/03/10/java_bash_cygwin.html)

For tutorial purposes I **highly recommend** the cloudera **demo VM and tutorial**:
https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Cloudera%27s+Hadoop+Demo+VM

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/Hadoop+Tutorial#HadoopTutorial-Purpose

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I already have HBase/Hadoop running on Linux and on VMs.

In fact for developing I use a local VM. I just wanted to get rid of the extra layer of a VM.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

The first error looks like Java is not being found, but the second error is clearly coming from Java, so the combination of these two errors is somewhat confusing.  Are you sure that they are both being produced by the same script at the same time?

The second error is caused by not having the zookeeper jar file on the classpath.  Try modifying the script or copying the jar into the hadoop lib dir.

Comment: It is Standalone mode - there is no HBase user

Comment: How are you getting a class not found error if Java is not found?  Is the JAVA_HOME error old?

Comment: hbase-config.sh is called upon startup with ./start-hbase - hbase-config creates that output

Comment: @Shain: You are right - the first error comes from the script and the second one comes from Java directly. I managed to get rid of the Java error by manually setting the classpath to find zookeeper but still the first one is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

`hbase_classpath` is not need, just change `zookeeper.jar` to `azookeeper.jar`