# Install HBase on windows: Get zookeeper KeeperException

Tags: windows, cygwin, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I try to install HBase on windows. I follow all the steps of this website:
[http://ics.upjs.sk/~novotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows](http://ics.upjs.sk/%7Enovotnyr/blog/334/setting-up-hbase-on-windows)

When I try to start HBase I got the following error and I can't find the solution:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/zookeeper/KeeperException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
localhost: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Can you help me to understand?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that with recent versions, there's an issue in the way the classpath list of jars is built, so you need to include a dummy file that comes after "zookeeper" alphabetically otherwise the last file in the directory gets skipped. Touch "zzz.jar" (creating a 0 byte file) in the hbase/lib directory, then try starting it again.

I originally also added the hbase/lib directory in the HBASE_CLASSPATH in the hbase_env.sh file, but I suspect the trick above would have sufficed.

See shapkin's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19981264